# Font changes on Preview 2017 for text on photo

Tags: photos, preview, font

I can find no answers to changing the font size on a photo in Preview. It is not a PDF. 
All the answers I've seen are for PDF or from years ago.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Markup feature to add annotations to the image, you need to have the Markup Toolbar enabled:

[image]

Text options are then available:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So simple when you know how. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If this is indeed the solution you were looking for, then accept it as the best answer!